# WPF Designer for Treeview is complaining about not finding a type in a local namespace

Tags: wpf

```
<Fluent:RibbonWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Fluent="urn:fluent-ribbon"
        xmlns:Data="clr-namespace:DispatchData;assembly=DispatchData"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:DispatchWPF2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Dispatch Desktop" Height="600" Width="1000" Icon="Images/app1.png">

<Grid Grid.Row="1" ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="175"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <TreeView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="DataTree" MinWidth="175" BorderThickness="0">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:DispatchTreeTerritoryItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientLocations}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:DispatchTreeClientLocationItem}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientName,StringFormat='({0}) '}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Fluent:RibbonWindow>
```

I get the following error in the Error List window...

> The name "DispatchTreeTerritoryItem" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:DispatchWPF2".

This error takes me to the XAML, TreeView, HierarchicalDataTemplate - with blue squiggles under `DataType="{x:Type`.  I know for a fact that the `DispatchTreeTerritoryItem` class exists within the `DispatchWPF2` namespace.

This shows as an Error in the Error Window, however it does not prevent compiling, nor running the application.  At runtime, everything looks as expected.  I see the treeview looking just as I would expect, loaded with the data I expect.

Unfortunately this Error is preventing the XAML designer from showing in Visual Studio 2017.  The Design surface changes to a grey box with the words "Invalid Markup".  I'm kinda a visually oriented guy so this is quite annoying for me.

[image: VS 2017 Screenshot]

Any thoughts on how to make this Error go away and give me back my design surface?

Comment: You'r error is within .cs file and you showing as .xaml, how can we help you then? Check brackets, your TerrorityItem is probably within another subnamespace

Comment: @sTrenat: can you clarify your comment?  As double-clicking on the Error in the Error Window takes me to the XAML (with blue squiggles), and its the XAML designer that I want working again.. I'm not sure how the error is within the code behind.   I did check the namespace.  The `DispatchTreeTerritoryItem` type lives directly in the `DispatchWPF2` namespace.

Comment: Try to use this:   xmlns:self="clr-namespace:DispatchWPF2;assembly=DispatchWPF2". or build your solution as release and then again as debug

Comment: Same result.  No change.

Comment: Rebooting seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting seems to have solved the issue.